# W3 Total Cache Plugin with WP 3 MultiUser

Tags: multisite, redirect, plugin-w3-total-cache, htaccess

I'm having some strange behavior with my W3 Total Cache solution working on my multi-user Wordpress 3 installation. The multi-user is setup to use sub directories, and I'm using all types of caching in W3. My suspicion is that my problem has something to do with the .htaccess file.

Periodically (but not consistently) navigating to certain parts of the site will end up redirecting to the wrong place. For example if I goto /corporate/ which is one of the subsite directories, it will redirect to /directives/corporate-training/ which is a single post of a different sub-site. This only happens occasionally, sometimes it is not a problem (which is why I think it is somehow related to page caching)

The behavior suggests that somewhere in the redirect rules, it occasionally forgets to check for other sub-sites, and instead tries to match /corporate/ to the closest post slug in a different site.

Looking for any guidance on where to look for the problem.

Comment: I wonder why this question was downvoted without any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There several possible scenarios:

1. For some reason W3 is not properly configured or configuration was improperly applied to .htaccess files.
2. W3 is properly configured but has compatibility issues with some part of your setup.
3. This has nothing to do with W3 at all and comes from some other part of your setup or server.

From this little details it is hard to make educated guess. Aside from generic unnstall/reinstall W3 I can only suggest to try contacting W3 developer with oyur configuration details and your hosting support to check server logs for any visible issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable the rewrite log and see what rules are getting matched? You'll need to do it in the .htaccess or the apache config directly. Keep in mind, this level of logging will slow down the site..